# Stream media to remote client (native desktop client, web, anything is fine)

Tags: windows-7, video, media, video-streaming

There is a server (Intel Atom dual-core CPU with Windows XP installed on it). The 'server' got a huge bandwidth, which I could easily use to stream media to my home PC where I have a simple ADSL connection. (Like I can download tons of videos... about free software conferences of course, and then stream one to my home PC.)

I've tried only **VLC** and **Windows Media Player** so far. Both are unusable. I had to wrangle with VLC a lot. Basically it lets me to stream, but I can't control the stream. I can't skip, jump. Nothing.

I tried to enable the HTTP, and the Flash interface for VLC. It doesn't work. The flash window will appear, but nothing inside.

**WMP** is also dead. I tried setting up the Live ID, then opened up the ports, set everything listed in tutorials. But I just can't see the remote PC. Everything is fine according to WMP's self-check. Yet, nothing.

Any web-based (like using XAMPP and a script), or flash based, or a native software like VLC based solution would work. Just want to stream a file, and have control over the stream. (Re-converting the video for the stream is not neccessary, but a buffer would be fine in that case, so I could watch 1080p videos too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Plex](http://plexapp.com/). It streams my films, TV series, photos and music locally and when I'm out using a mobile connection.  The content is transcoded on the fly to suit your available bandwidth and client type.

You can control the stream too just as if you were viewing it directly in a normal player too.